# Disable dhcp server for esp32 softAP

Tags: arduino, dhcp, esp32, disable

I want to use a esp32 with a static private address in softAP mode, but only have two stations connect to it.  Is there a way to do disable dhcp server? I still need the AP functionality but want a very small network.  I could use a restrictive subnet, but want to shut down dhcp instead.  Using Adafruit Huzzah and arduino IDE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> AT+CWDHCP:   Enables/disables DHCP.

https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_at_instruction_set_and_examples_en.pdf

Page 18, Chapter 4.2.8

Comment: How will AT commands affect flashed code?  If I upload Arduino code, then use AT to disable dhcp - does this work?  I was hoping for an Arduino example in case of reboot...